# Implementing class of Java interface with generic types: warning "Type safety: The return type ... needs unchecked conversion to conform"

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following Java super interface:

```
public interface IdProvider<T, ID> {
  <S extends T> ID idOf(S entity);
  ID nextId();
  <S extends T> S entityWithId(S entity, ID id);
}
```

and the following implementing (inner) class:

```
  class TestingEntityUuidProvider implements IdProvider<TestingEntity, UUID>{
    @Override
    public UUID idOf(TestingEntity entity) {...}

    @Override
    public UUID nextId() {...}

    @Override
    public TestingEntity entityWithId(TestingEntity entity, UUID id) {...}
  }
```

While the `idOf()` method and everything else works fine, the `entityWithId()` method causes the following compiler warning:

```
Type safety: The return type TestingEntity for entityWithId(TestingEntity, UUID) from the type TestingEntityUuidProvider needs unchecked conversion to conform to S from the type IdProvider<T,ID>
```

Can anybody explain why this is the case exactly, and what would be a better alternative?

P.S. The `TestingEntity` is just a simple POJO with getters:

```
public class TestingEntity {
  private final UUID id;
  private final String content;
...
}
```

Comment: In the interface, what was the thought process behind adding the type parameter `S` to `idOf` and `entityWithId`? Why not just `ID idOf(T entity);` and `T entityWithId(T entity, ID id);`? That's what the `TestingEntityUuidProvider` implemented, after all.

Comment: The code using the id provider uses the generic sub class, like so:   

```@Override
  public <S extends T> S save(S entity) { 
     final ID idToBeSaved = idToBeSavedFor(entity);
    
   S entityToBeSaved = idProvider.entityWithId(entity, idToBeSaved);
   entities.put(idToBeSaved, entityToBeSaved);
   return entityToBeSaved;
`}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<S extends T>` part of the method.

With this notation you define a new *method type parameter* `S` that is *some specific subtype* of `T`.

The way your `entityWithId` method is defined you could pass in a `SubclassOfTestingEntity` and also get a `SubclassOfTestingEntity` back.

If you just return the input in `entityWithid` that will work and callers will know that the return type of that method matches the type of the first parameter.

If, however, you somehow construct a new object in that method, then you'll have to do some shenanigans to ensure that the return type is actually of the same type as the input (or do an unsafe cast if you *don't* make sure).

In either way, you must re-defined the type-parameter in your implementation:

```
@Override
public <S extends TestingEntity> S entityWithId(S entity, UUID id) {...}
```

Also: there seems to be absolutely no reason for `<S extends T>` to be present on `idOf`: simply defining it as `ID idOf(T entity)` would be sufficient, work exactly the same and is much simpler to read.

Comment: Good point with `ID idOf(T entity)`, I changed it. Now concerning the other signature, I originally did what you proposed, i.e. created the following method, but it leads to a compile error: `@Override
    public <S extends TestingEntity> S entityWithId(S entity, UUID id) {
      return new TestingEntity(id, entity.getContent());
    }`. Why? What to do about it? (I guess that's the shenanigans you talked about)

Comment: That's not a valid implementation of that method. The method promises to return an object of whatever type S that is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

```
<S extends T> S entityWithId(S entity, ID id);
```

The contract says *"return something that extends T"*.

```
TestingEntity entityWithId(TestingEntity entity, UUID id)
```

The implementation says *"return TestingEntity"*, or, in the interface's terms, *"return T"*. It's a mismatch in definition, thus the warning.

If you were to follow the convention precisely, it would be like

```
<S extends TestingEntity> S entityWithId(S entity, UUID id)
```

@Sweeper makes a good point in the comments - you could have simply used `T` instead of `<S extends T>` (unless you have a good reason for it, which we can't see).